# LocalDateTime saved with the wrong type in MongoDB with SpringBoot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, java-time

I have this simple Java type:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class AnnotationSample {
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
}
```

Following is an instance of the AnnotationSample type as saved in MongoDB:
[The LocalDateTime field is stored with the Object type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5p6B.png)

When I try to find my AnnotationSample back with Java/SpringBoot, I get the following error:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
>
> Decoding into a 'AnnotationSample' failed with the following exception:
> Failed to decode 'AnnotationSample'. Decoding 'startDate' errored with: Could not decode into LocalDateTime, expected 'DATE_TIME' BsonType but got 'DOCUMENT'.
>
> A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.

My dependencies:

- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.3.0
- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.12.9
- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.2.3
- org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Neumann-SR7
- org.mongodb:bson:4.3.0

I used about any tip'n'tricks I could find on the Matrix, to no avail. I even added this to my configuration:

```
@Bean
public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
    return new MongoCustomConversions(new ArrayList<>(Jsr310Converters.getConvertersToRegister()));
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you use `LocalDateTime.now()` to store the document?

Comment: No, I don't. The LocalDateTime object is created by parsing an ISO-formatted String.

Comment: It looks like you are storing an object and not a simple time string. So mongo can't autoparse it back to LocalDataTime on read. I am not recommending to do it like this. Just store your `ISODate` if it looks like `2021-07-28T13:04:44.945Z`. `LocalDateTime.parse()`

Comment: Thanks @DaniR. I Have quite a few workarounds at hand yet. But what I cannot understand is, first, how come the MongoDB driver is able to store a LocalDateTime as-is but is not able retrieve it; and then, why are LocalDateTime objects not handled properly when JSR310 is supposed to be implemented for a good deal of time?

Comment: That's a good question. In our case it is working out of the box, so i suppose you are storing a different type.